# How to replace the span text using class name inside div

Tags: jquery

How can I replace replace "Sunday" and "Monday" with "SUN" and "MON" using jquery in the HTML below.

```
<table> 
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>
        <div class="xyz">
          <a href="www.google.com"> 20 may <span>Sunday</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div>
        <div class="xyz">
          <a href="www.google.com"> 21 may <span>Monday</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `:contains` function. What it does it it finds what text you are looking for and replace to your target text. Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AeGBq/). The only thing is you will have to execute it individually for each word you want to replace.

Html code

```
<div class="container"><span>Sunday</span></div>
<div class="container"><span>Monday</span></div>
```

Jquery code

```
$(".container span:contains('Sunday')").html('Sun');//Replace to Sun
$(".container span:contains('Monday')").html('Mon');//Replace to Mon
```

Comment: how to exchange SUN and '20 may' in the above code like 'SUN 20 May'

Comment: Here is the updated code. It is bit longer process. Because you don't have any specific class on week. [http://jsfiddle.net/AeGBq/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/AeGBq/2/)

Comment: If your problem has been solved you should accept this answer so more people willing to help your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NvUPd/1/).  Here's the code that does the actual work:

```
$(".xyz").each(function() {
    var theSpan = $(this).find("span").first();

    switch (theSpan.text()) {
        case "Sunday":
            theSpan.text("SUN");
            break;
        case "Monday":
            theSpan.text("MON");
            break;
        // include additional case statements
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that this particular method works only for the exact layout that you have because it uses a `find` call and then uses `first` to get only a single `span` tag within the structure of the original `div`.

If you were to provide a class in the `span` that contains the text to replace, you would get more consistent results and might not need the `find` call.

---

As a variation to this, you could use some string manipulation if what you're really looking for is "the all-caps abbreviation of the full name of each day."  Instead of the big `switch` statement, you could accomplish the same with this code ([also available in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NvUPd/2/)):

```
$(".xyz").each(function() {
    var theSpan = $(this).find("span").first();
    theSpan.text(theSpan.text().substr(0,3).toUpperCase());
});
```

Comment: The suggested alternative approach to applying the change is based on the assumption the you want only *the first 3 letters* of the full name of each day.  This was extrapolated from the examples provided in the question.  If you need something other than exactly 3 letters regardless of the day, then you'll probably need to stick with the `switch` and explicitly enumerate each day's replacement text.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function(){
        $(".xyz").each(function(){
         var obj=$(this).text($(this).text();
             obj.replace('Sunday','Sun'));
         obj.replace('Monday','Mon'));
        });
    });

Did you mean this?
```

Comment: Calling `$(this)` so many times is inefficient.  The result of that call should be cached into a variable and referenced that way within the `each` function.  Otherwise, this is also a viable solution.

Comment: It's the act of converting the javascript "this" object into the jQuery object using the `$` that's slow.  It doesn't matter how you find the original object.  It's the conversion from DOM to jQuery that should be cached.

Comment: how to exchange SUN and '20 may' in the above code like 'SUN 20 May'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(".xyz span:contains('Sunday')").text('Sun');
$(".xyz span:contains('Monday')").text('Mon');
```